# How to read user & password from text file

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection

Hello guys I am using a simple password protection script in PHP like this:

```
$LOGIN_INFORMATION = array(
    'user' => 'pass',
);

if (!USE_USERNAME && !in_array($pass, $LOGIN_INFORMATION)
    || (USE_USERNAME && ( !array_key_exists($login, $LOGIN_INFORMATION) ||
        $LOGIN_INFORMATION[$login] != $pass ) )
```

How can I change this to read the user and password from a text file formatted like:

```
user:pass
```

?

Here is the full script i hope you can help me plz
[Click Here](http://www.zubrag.com/downloads/password-protect.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
$data = file('userdata.txt');  // format user:pas

$data=array_map('trim', $data);

if(in_array($pass, $data))
{
   echo 'login is ok';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will help you.

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$exp = explode(':', $file);
$LOGIN_INFORMATION[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
```